# When is the Master-Secret calculated? And who calculates it?

Tags: ssl

I think I remember, that I read that the master secret is calculated from both - the server and the client - after the Client Key Exchange. Is this true?

Comment: My understanding is both client/server keys mix together and create the shared secret.  It would be calculated on  both ends, I think.

Comment: I know what it is but I'm interested in when it is created and who is doing that

Comment: **Both** are doing it. 'At both ends'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The client and server exchange random numbers and a special number
>   called the Pre-Master Secret. These numbers are combined with
>   additional data permitting client and server to create their shared
>   secret, called the Master Secret. The Master Secret is used by client
>   and server to generate the write MAC secret

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380513%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: according to your url question number 2 is answered: `The server and client each generate the Master Secret and session keys based on the Pre-Master Secret.`

Comment: If the server has requested client authentication, the server attempts to authenticate the client. If the client cannot be authenticated, the session is terminated. If the client can be successfully authenticated, the server uses its private key to decrypt the pre-master secret, then performs a series of steps (which the client also performs, starting from the same pre-master secret) to generate the master secret. Both server and client create master, step 6 http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19424-01/820-4811/gbfqu/index.html